# javascript loses variable value after a validation function

Tags: javascript, jquery

i tried few days to make this code working but today i got the idea to ask some help. Here is the problem: when i try to send the value of my input fields to my params variable, i just get nothing, an empty value. However when i remove my validation function,

```
$(document).input.hasAttribute('required').each(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
        alert('Please fill all the fields');
    }
});
```

all the parameters are in my url : ?rpt=123456&etc...etc...

Do you know why i loose my variable value on the way? If yes how to solve this?

Thanks for the help

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#vb_report_date").datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    autoHide: true
  });
  jQuery("#vb_verify_button").click(function() {
    check_required_inputs(true);
  });
});

function check_required_inputs(hasbeenSubmited) {
  var params = "";
  if (hasbeenSubmited) {
    $(document).input.hasAttribute('required').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == "") {
        alert('Please fill all the fields');
      }
    });
    params = "?rpt=" + jQuery("#vb_report_no").val() + "&d=" + jQuery("#vb_report_date").val() + "&pin=" + jQuery("#vb_verif_pin").val();
  }
  window.location.href = "verify-reports.php" + params;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>

  <form id="requiredform" class="verify-box">
    <input type="text" id="vb_report_no" placeholder="Report Number" size="22" data-error="This field is required." class="" required>
    <input type="text" id="vb_report_date" placeholder="Date of Issue" size="12" class="hasDatepicker" data-error="This field is required." required>
    <input type="text" id="vb_verif_pin" placeholder="Verification PIN" size="22">
    <input type="submit" value="Verify" id="vb_verify_button">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `.hasAttribute('required')` will return a `Boolean` and you can't iterate over it. You must be getting a syntax error with that code. Have you checked the console?

Comment: Thanks for you answer mate! Required attribute directly on the field not work on all safari browsers, thats why i used js for this, then if i just focus on other browsers so the problem was: the form was submitted right away after displaying quickly: "This field is required".. If i submit it directly i will not have anymore the url and i need this url for the next steps.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava thanks for your answer. no error in the console =/

Comment: Unless you have some other code/third party plugin, the code `$(document).input.hasAttribute` *will* give error: `VM146:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasAttribute' of undefined`.  Then your function will stop running and the submit of the button will continue (ie the form will submit and reset the page).

Answer (score 0):

To select all required inputs in the document, use `$(document).find('input[required]')`.

Your function should look like:

```js
function check_required_inputs(hasbeenSubmited) {

  // do the check only when hasBeenSubmited
  if (hasbeenSubmited) {

    // assume inputs are filled
    var isValid = true;

    // check required inputs
    $(document).find('input[required]').each(function () {
      // input value is missing
      if ($(this).val() == "") {
        alert('Please fill all the fields');
        isValid = false;
      }
    });

    // do the redirect if isValid
    if (isValid) {
      // make query string
      var params = "?rpt=" + $("#vb_report_no").val() + "&d=" + $("#vb_report_date").val() + "&pin=" + $("#vb_verif_pin").val();

      // do the redirect
      window.location.href = "verify-reports.php" + params;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: just tried. Now i got the alert working when fields are empty but automatically redirected to the url with empty parameters rpt=&d=&pin=. But once i fill paramters so im redirected to the same page without parameters only a question mark: ?

Comment: There should be validation logic involved to check if inputs are filled. I've updated my answer, adding some logic to do the redirect only if required inputs are filled. Feel free to adjust to your needs.

Comment: With your new edit i progressed a lot, now after the alert we are not forcing anymore the redirect after check as we have the if statement. Thanks But unfortunately, the redirect not work, we still have nothing as parameters only a question mark : ?

Comment: Are you sure that ```params``` is properly formatted? What do you get when doing ```console.log(params)``` instead of the redirect? Maybe the ids are incorrect? Is the date (#vb_report_date) properly formatted? Also, as a general consitency concern, I'd suggest using ```$``` everywhere instead of ```jQuery```.

Comment: Ok thanks for advices. I tried to replace by a console log as you suggested but not any new line appears once submitted. So nothing happened but we have a kind of redirection then the ? is added to the url then we come back to the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **onsubmit** method.

```
<form id="requiredform" class="verify-box" onsubmit="return getdata()" >
    <input type="text" id="vb_report_no" placeholder="Report Number" size="22" data-error="This field is required." class="" required>
    <input type="text" id="vb_report_date" placeholder="Date of Issue" size="12" class="hasDatepicker" data-error="This field is required." required>
    <input type="text" id="vb_verif_pin" placeholder="Verification PIN" size="22">
    <input type="submit" value="Verify" id="vb_verify_button">
</form>

function getdata() {
  check_required_inputs(true);
}
```

Try [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) with an [attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) selector to get all required inputs in the document.

```
document.getElementById('requiredform').querySelectorAll("[required]")
```

Now function will be like this,

```
function check_required_inputs(hasbeenSubmited) {
  var params = "";
  console.log(hasbeenSubmited)
  if (hasbeenSubmited) {
     document.getElementById('requiredform').querySelectorAll("[required]").forEach(function (element) {
       if ($(element).val() == "") {
          alert('Please fill all the fields');
       }
     });
  params = "?rpt=" + jQuery("#vb_report_no").val() + "&d=" + jQuery("#vb_report_date").val() + "&pin=" + jQuery("#vb_verif_pin").val();
  }
 window.location.href = "verify-reports.php" + params;
```

}

For more details: [how to get value from a form before submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30937263/how-to-get-value-from-a-form-before-submit)

**Check the working snippet here..**

```js
    function check_required_inputs(hasbeenSubmited) {
      var params = "";
      console.log(hasbeenSubmited)
      if (hasbeenSubmited) {     
     document.getElementById('requiredform').querySelectorAll("[required]").forEach(function (element) {     
     if ($(element).val()== "") {
      alert('Please fill all the fields');
     }     
        });
     params = "?rpt=" + jQuery("#vb_report_no").val() + "&d=" + jQuery("#vb_report_date").val() + "&pin=" + jQuery("#vb_verif_pin").val();
      }
     console.log(params);
    window.location.href = "verify-reports.php" + params;
   }

function getdata() {
  check_required_inputs(true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    
<form id="requiredform" class="verify-box" onsubmit="return getdata()" >
 <input type="text" id="vb_report_no" placeholder="Report Number" size="22" data-error="This field is required." class="" required>
 <input type="text" id="vb_report_date" placeholder="Date of Issue" size="12" class="hasDatepicker" data-error="This field is required." required>
 <input type="text" id="vb_verif_pin" placeholder="Verification PIN" size="22">
 <input type="submit" value="Verify" id="vb_verify_button">
</form>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, tried but it not works. Url still empty

Comment: pass element variable on foreach loop, you will get value by using $(element).val()

Comment: thanks but still same issue with this new edits: i don't have the alert and not the parameters too once fields are filled and form submitted. I just have a question mark after url (don't have rpt=&d=&pin= neither rpt=XXXX&d=XX/XX/XXXX&pin=XXX

Comment: you can't submit the form if the required fields has empty values. Therefore you won't receive alert box anymore

Comment: right. after tested your code, we are not redirected automatically after empty fields and get the alert. But redirection still not have any parameters unfortunately only a question mark: ?

Comment: thanks a lot but still have the problem. I tried the code in jsfiddle, it works too. But not on my server. Unbelievable. I tried to deactivate the htaccess in case but still not work im still redirected to the same form nce everything filled and nothing in the url.

Comment: Just tried in http https too but still the same issue

Comment: checkes yes, i even tried to copy paste the jsfiddle code to my page and its not work. Ill try to put the code in another server for check, ill update you soon